# taxquery taxonomy get terms

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I have onnly VERY LIMITED knowledge in programming and coding.

On our website (travel agency) we offer different sample-trips sorted by regions (Mexico, Middle-America, Southamerica and other countries), see here: [Neue Welt Reisen/trips](https://neue-welt-reisen.de/reiserouten/)

When you select a trip e.g. [Costa Rica](https://neue-welt-reisen.de/reiserouten/costa-rica-mietwagenreise/) you will find other sample trips at the bottom of the page. These trips should be selected from the same region, in this case Middle-America and not from the 3 other regions. There is a script that should this, but the results are only trips from the region Mexico. So my question is: How do I select the example-trips from the same region? Here is the code:

```
<div class="promo-trips-container">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'ausfluge',
        'showposts'     => 3,
        'orderby'       => 'rand',
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'reisezweck',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'mexiko', 'middle-america', 'south-america', 'other' ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $trips_list = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
```

THANK YOU

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if `$trips_list` is the sample trips section, and you want the sample trips to only show trips with the same terms - you'd find the current trips term and argue that in your WP_Query.

```
// this trips terms
$tripTerms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'reisezweck');

// if each trip only has one term (as its a location)
// we'll use the first of the array array of terms
// and we'll now have our current trips term
$tripTerm = $tripTerms[0]->slug;

// you can uncomment and use instead if it's possible a trip has multiple terms: 
// make an array of ID of current trips terms
/* $tripTerm = array();
foreach ($tripTerms as $aTripTerms) 
    $tripTerm[] = $aTripTerms->slug; */

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'ausfluge',
    'showposts'     => 3,
    'orderby'       => 'rand',
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'reisezweck',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tripTerm,
        ),
    ),
);
$trips_list = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I've assumed each trip would have only one term. I've added commented code incase a trip could have multiple.

Comment: Dear David,  Thank you very much, that was exactly what I wanted to know. It works fine. Have a nice day.  Paul